# If $ad - bc = 0$, then $\begin{cases} ax + by = j \\ cx + dy = k \end{cases}$ has no unique solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

#### Problem:

I have an exercise in an assignment, which is the following:

> Show, if $ad - bc = 0$, then $$ax + by = j \\ cx + dy = k$$ has no unique
>   solutions.

I first have problems understanding what unique solutions means, but now I think  have to demonstrate that the system above has not just one solution but more.

I had a hint from one of my professors to use forward/backward substitution to prove the following problem, but I must admit I would not know how to do it.

---

#### What I have tried?

I have tried to isolate an $x$ in one equation and replace it in the other, for example, isolating $x$ of the first equation and replace it in the second:

$$x = \frac{j - by}{a}$$

$$c\left(\frac{j - by}{a} \right) + dy = k$$

If I try to solve this, I think I will not arrive at any helpful conclusion.

I have tried to apply the *hint* of one of the professors to use forward/backward substitution. I must admit I am not so familiar with these concepts.

I am not sure if this is backward/forward substitution, but maybe one example where I use these concepts was to solve a system of equations like this:

$$\begin{matrix}7x + 7y - 7z = 0 \\ 0 + y + z = 7 \\ 0 + 0 -z - 7 \end{matrix}$$

(Zeros are there just to align the system.)

What I think I have tried to do is a backward substitution. I have started by getting $z$ from the last equation: $$z = -7$$

Then, I replaced $-7$ in the equation in the middle, we obtain $$y - 7 = 7 \\ y = 14$$

Finally, we can replace $y$ and $z$ in the first equation and we obtain

$$7x + (7 * 14) - (7 * -7) = 0$$

$$x = -21$$

---

#### Questions

1. Is my process of backward substitution in my example correct?
2. How would I solve my original problem using backward/forward substitution?

---

I remember that what I have to demonstrate is that it has no unique solutions, so probably I have to show it has more than one solution. For example, that for different $x$ values we get different $y$ values...

Comment: Do you know what a determinant is? Because $\det \left ( \begin{matrix} a&b \\ c&d\end{matrix}\right )=ad-bc$.

Comment: @Reveillark Given the OP's level, that's very much begging the question...

Comment: You could just continue with your own approach: $c\left(\frac{j - by}{a} \right) + dy = k$. Notice that I change your minus sign to plus sign. It was a typo. Solve this for $y$. If $ad-bc=0$, can you find $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Continue with your own approach, as you said, you get

$$y(ad - bc) = ak - cj \\ y * 0 = ak - cj$$

This means either it has no solution, if $ak-cj\neq 0$, which gives you a contradiction; or it has infinitely many solution, if $ak-cj=0$, since this equation becomes $0=0$, in which case you have only one equation for two variables.

Comment: @Rinzler: Yes, this is correct. This is also equivalent to say the two equations are essentially the same, or they are dependent of each other, which is a concept which you probably have not learned yet. However what you've done is manipulating them to see that they don't give you more than 1 condition. And 1 condition with 2 variables could have infinitely many solutions. Can you tell me what part of this argument makes you think it is strange?

Comment: @Rinzler: I see. Well, giving a simpler example: if you have two equations $x=y, y=x$. Do you see that they have infinitely many solutions? This is essentially the same case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,ad = bc\,$ then $\,(x,y)\,$ a solution $\,\Rightarrow\, (x+d,y-c)\,$ a solution.

**Key Idea** $\ $ The map  $\,{\bf  x}\mapsto \bf A  x\,$ is *linear*, therefore  if $\, \color{#c00}{{\bf A}\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\ y_0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}}\,$ then

$\qquad\ \ {\bf A} \begin{bmatrix}x\!+\!x_0\\ y\!+\!y_0\end{bmatrix} = {\bf A}\left( \begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}\! +\! \begin{bmatrix}x_0\\ y_0\end{bmatrix}\right) = {\bf A}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} + \color{#c00}{{\bf A}\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}} =\, {\bf A} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

i.e. $\quad \color{#c00}{{\bf A x_0 = 0}}\,\Rightarrow\, {\bf A}(\bf x+x_0) = A {\bf x} + \color{#c00}{A{\bf x_0}} = A{\bf x}$

hence  $\ {\bf Ax} = {\bf b}\,\Rightarrow\, {\bf A}({\bf x+x_0)} = {\bf Ax} = \bf b\, $

thus  $\,{\bf x}\,$ a solution $\,\Rightarrow\, {\bf x+x_0}\,$ a solution, for any $\,{\bf x_0}\,$ such that $\, {\bf A x_0 = 0}.$

This is a *fundamental* property of linear equations, e.g. differential equations, recurrences, etc.

Comment: @Rinzler See the edit to my answer. This key property will come to the fore as you learn more linear algebra.

Comment: @Rinzler Notice that the values I chose $\,{\bf x} = (b,-a)\,$ and $\,(d.-c)\,$ are solutions of the above red system, with the RHS $= 0.$ Please feel welcome to ask further questions if something is not clear.